# Git Commit after merge opens VIM

Tags: git, vim

I did a merge of 2 files and now Im trying to commit but it opens VIM with the following data and now I'm completely lost. (I have no experience with VIM)

```
Merge branch 'master' of nodester.com:/node/git/lolcoder/****-******

Conflicts:
        .gitignore
        server.js
#
# It looks like you may be committing a merge.
# If this is not correct, please remove the file
#       .git/MERGE_HEAD
# and try again.


# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#   
#       .project
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
".git/COMMIT_EDITMSG" 19L, 521C                               1,1           All
```

What do I do from here?

Here is the scenario:

I had a node.js project on github, now I'm trying to push this to nodester's git repo (so I now have 2 remotes for my project). But before I can push to nodester, I needed to fix 2 files that conflicted with the ones generated on nodester for me. I solved the conflicts with `git merge -y` and now I want to commit then push.

This is the error I get when trying to push to nodester:

```
Nodester!
To git@nodester.com:/node/git/lolcoder/****-**************.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@nodester.com:/node/git/lolcoder/****-************.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with node.js or nodster please only use appropriate tags.  In this case GIT.

Comment: I think this is a "bad" feature of git. It just make it less automation.And I have to wrap the git command to make it automation again.`--message "save"` works for me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Git is opening vim because your environment variable EDITOR is set to vim, and Git believes you need to provide a commit message for the merge operation, therefore it is opening an editor for you to type one in.

You can fix this by changing your environment's EDITOR variable to something you prefer, or by providing a --message "this is my commit message" argument after `git merge -y`

Comment: I did `git commit -- "message"`

Comment: What's the default value for the EDITOR variable, this didn't happen to me before and I will like to return to the default behavior.

Comment: The default value varies from system to system.  I have no idea what yours was before.  If you didn't permanently change the EDITOR variable (in your .bashrc or similar), then you can probably just open a new terminal and be back to normal.

Answer (score 7):

If what you want is to perform the merge and avoid opening any text editor, you can add [`--no-edit`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html#_options) to your merge command so that it won't open the editor for the commit message.

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to totally skip the text editor and use the default merge message instead, just add the following line into your `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file:

```
export GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no
```